# Adding Dynamic Node in D3 Tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im learning d3 js layout and having difficulty in adding node to the tree layout.

Hoping for a way of adding dynamic node(children) after clicking the parent node.

My current implementation do add the node, but instead of updating it, it added new children and keep the child from before.

Can someone help me understand the problem and a correct way of approaching this.

Here is my code and my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fretwiz/5rf9rmq6/) (click on the root node):

HTML

```
<div id="body"> 
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

JS

```
var margin = {top: 100, right: 50, bottom: 100, left: 50},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .separation(function(a, b) { return a.children === b.children ? 1 : 1.2; })
    .size([width, height]); 

 var svg = d3.select("body")
    .attr("bgcolor", "#fff")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dataOne = {
  "name": "Mike and Marcia",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Children",
      "children": [
        { "name": "Mikael" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var drawTree = function(source){

 var nodes = tree.nodes(source);
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

 var boxes = node.selectAll('g')
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .append('rect')
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 40)
            .attr("fill", "tan")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 50; });


  boxes.on("click", function(d,i){
   clickOutside(d);
  });


};

var clickOutside = function(value){
  var newData = {
        "name": "Mike and Marcia",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Children",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Mikael"
            }]
        },{
            "name": "Pets",
            "children": []
        }]
     };

 drawTree(newData);    
 console.log(value);

}

drawTree(dataOne);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing the new graph over the old graph.

That is the reason why you get the impression that its adding child to the old parent.

So the correct approach would be to

1. draw the graph
2. remove all nodes that is not required.

**So 1st point**

```
 var nodedata = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d){ /* function which return the Unique id of each node */ return d.name;})

    //make all the nodes.
    nodedata.enter().append('g')
            .attr("class", "node")
            .append('rect')
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", 40)
            .attr("fill", "tan")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 50; })
            .on("click", function(d,i){
             clickOutside(d);
            });
```

**2nd point**

Remove all nodes which are intersection of first set of passed data and the second set of passed data.

```
nodedata.exit().remove();
```

**Last point add children to parent**

You can change the JSON

```
var dataOne = {
  "name": "Mike and Marcia",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Children",
      "children": [
        { "name": "Mikael" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Add whatever structure JSON and pass it down your `drawTree function`

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o3nfw7qj/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the short but comprehensive explanation @Cyril. That's exactly how i want it to work. I do have follow up question to further understand d3 concepts. Is it okay if i directed the question to you?